# Return true if numbers are between 10 and 200 with if in php

Tags: php

```
<a href="post.php?id=4&rows=<?php if ($_GET['rows']) echo $_GET['rows'] + 10; else echo "10"; ?>">Expand</a>
```

Can I get this to only return true if the numbers are between 10 and 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this condition expression:

```
if ($_GET['rows'] > 10 && $_GET['rows'] < 200)
```

It only evaluates to true if the value of `$_GET['rows']` is greater than 10 *and* smaller than 200. For inclusion of 10 and 200 use `>=` (greater or equal) and `<=` (smaller or equal) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're so inclined you might want to use the ternary operator here, i.e.

```
<a href="post.php?id=4&rows=<?php echo ($_GET['rows'] > 10 && $_GET['rows'] < 200) ? $_GET['rows'] + 10 : '10' ?>">Expand</a>
```

Some people despise it, I think it neatens things up in situations like this.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same... I don't see why some despise it. You could tighten it up even further by reducing it to:

<pre><code><a href="post.php?id=4&rows=<?= ($_GET['rows'] > 10 && $_GET['rows'] < 200) ? $_GET['rows'] + 10 : '10'; ?>">Expand</a>
</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($_GET['rows'] >= 10) && ($_GET['rows'] <= 200)) echo $_GET['rows'] + 10; else echo "10";
```

(assuming you want "10" and "200" to return true, otherwise just use '<' and '>' rather than '<=')